# post not recieving response from node express - node newbe

Tags: javascript, express, async-await, response

I have an Axios post function that I am using to post multipart form data to a Node.js Express endpoint using Multiparty to process the input fields.

The endpoint receives the data and inserts it in the database. I am trying to use the response status to trigger the form.reset() it all succeeds.

What can I do to get the response status in the post function?

Listener and Post:

```
let categories = []


const form = document.getElementById("category");
  
const formEvent = form.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let cat = new FormData(form);
  cat.append('userId',userId)
  await postCat(cat);
});

const postCat  = async (cat) =>{
   
    await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/category-api/addNew/?', 
         cat, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        }
      )
         .then( (res) => {
            if ( res.status(200)){
              form.reset();
              document.getElementById('shim').style.display = document.getElementById('msgbx').style.display = "none";
            }  
            else if (!res.status(200)) {
                  return null
              }
          })
          .catch((e) => {
              console.log('ERROR ERROR', e, 'ERROR ERROR')
          })
}
```

Endpoint:

```
router.post("/addNew/", async (req, res) => {

  let form = new multiparty.Form();

  let pros = [], cons = [];
  let newCategory = { pros, cons }

  await form.parse(req, async (err, fields) => { 
    await Object.keys(fields).forEach((property) => {
      
      if (fields[property].toString().length > 0 && fields[property].toString() !== ' ') {
        if (property.startsWith('pro')) newCategory.pros.push(fields[property].toString())
        else if (property.startsWith('con')) newCategory.cons.push(fields[property].toString())
        else newCategory[property] = fields[property].toString();
      }
      if (property === ('name') && newCategory[property].length === 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Name must be included" });
      }
    }
    )
    categories.push(newCategory)     //inside form.parse is the key!
    await insertCat(newCategory)           
    await res.status(200).json(categories) 
  })
});
```

The await in  `await insertCat(newCategory)` and  `await res.status(200).json(categories)` were attempts to be sure the insertCat was complete before res.status fired. I'm not really sure if that is the problem. I also tried to use await where the res.status is in the post function. Previously, I was using `res.ok` instead of `res.status(200)`

I suspect the post is not waiting to receive the status. Can I make the post wait?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out res.status(200) is not a function, but res.status == 200  in the axios.post function works.

Answer (score 1):

Axios's `response.status` is not a function.
try `res.status === 200` or keep `res.ok` instead.